# Implementing long-polling with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, chat, comet, long-polling

I want to build a chat, based on JavaScript (jQuery will be used for AJAX) and PHP.

I've heard a good way of doing this is to use long-polling.

I do understand the idea, but I don't know how to implement it on the server side.

An infinite loop sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Using PHP for that is not a good idea. Have you considered using something like nodejs?

Comment: Agree that something non-blocking like node.js would probably be more ideal, but if that isn't an option you *can* implement in PHP as in my answer below.

Comment: Have you tried WebSockets instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to create an infinite loop, but you can set a timeout. Basically loop for X second waiting for some sort of data, and if that doesn't happen send a response to the client telling it that it needs to initiate a new request, which will have the same timeout period.

```
$source; // some data source - db, etc
$data = null; // our return data
$timeout = 30; // timeout in seconds
$now = time(); // start time

// loop for $timeout seconds from $now until we get $data
while((time() - $now) < $timeout) {
    // fetch $data
    $data = $source->getData();

    // if we got $data, break the loop
    if (!empty($data)) break;

    // wait 1 sec to check for new $data
    usleep(10000);
}

// if there is no $data, tell the client to re-request (arbitrary status message)
if (empty($data)) $data = array('status'=>'no-data');

// send $data response to client
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: why isn't processor's usage 100%
**1) SLEEP inside the loop** - processor runs the loop just once and then puts the script aside for a while and then comes back to it = no 100% processor usage

**2) END OF LOOP case A:** ((time() - $now) < $timeout) 
  = ((CURRENT_TIME - TIME_WHEN_THE_SCRIPT_STARTED) < TIMEOUT_SET_BY_YOU)

CURRENT_TIME - TIME_WHEN_THE_SCRIPT_STARTED = CURRENT_TIMEOUT 
so when CURRENT_TIMEOUT > TIMEOUT_SET_BY_YOU the loop will end

**3) END OF LOOP case B:** if (!empty($data)) break; = If the loop succeeds in getting the data it breaks=>ends

Answer (score 0):

implementing such kind of chat is not good idea in php, you can use [CometChat](http://www.cometchat.com/?r=AD3&gclid=CKyI8oWth7MCFVEP6wod6XEABQ), [Nodjs](http://nodejs.org/) and if you can not install scripts on your server than you can use Available APIs for Realtime Sending Data,

such as [Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/), [Pushemr](http://pusher.com/), [Beaconpush](http://beaconpush.com/).

Comment: Why is using PHP not a good idea, can you give more details on your reasoning?

Comment: Because PHP is not made for this... PHP can't handle large number of simultaneous connections .. and will be much overhead on php server.. so right technology for right requirement .. "A Sword cannot replace a Needle"