# How does Long Polling or Comet Work with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-polling, polling

I am making a notification system for my website. I want the logged in users to immediately noticed when a notification has made. As many people say, there're only a few ways of doing so.

One is writing some javascript code to ask the server "Are there any new notifications ?" at a given time interval. It's called "Polling" (I should be right).

Another is "Long Polling" or "Comet". As wikipedia says, long polling is similar to polling. Without asking everytime for new notifications, when new notifications are available, server sends them directly to the client.

So how can i use Long Polling with PHP ? (Don't need full source code, but a way of doing so)
What's its architecture/design really ?

Comment: `while (!$response) { $response = do_something(); sleep(1); } echo $response;`

Comment: Interesting question, just the one I was looking for. I will be putting a bounty for the answer +50

Comment: Long polling can be an issue for certain web-servers I think (been ages since I read anything about it though). Too many open connections etc.

Comment: @NickSlash What issues ? Is long polling not a good method ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with long polling, its just traditional web-servers are not designed to do it. @louis-philippe-huberdeau's answer explains it.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of long-polling is that you send a request which is then NOT responded or terminated by the server until some desired condition. I.e. server-side doesn't "finish" serving the request by sending the response. You can achieve this by keeping the execution in a loop on server-side.

Imagine that in each loop you do a database query or whatever is necessary for you to find out if the condition you need is now true. Only when it IS you break the loop and send the response to the client. When the client receives the response, it immediately re-sends the "long-polling" request so it wouldn't miss a next "notification".

A simplified example of the server-side PHP code for this could be:

```
// Set the loop to run 28 times, sleeping 2 seconds between each loop.
for($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++) {

    // find out if the condition is satisfied.
    // If YES, break the loop and send response     

    sleep(2);
}
// If nothing happened (the condition didn't satisfy) during the 28 loops,
// respond with a special response indicating no results. This helps avoiding
// problems of 'max_execution_time' reached. Still, the client should re-send the
// long-polling request even in this case.
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example, that works? I will be offering +50

Comment: A loop to check for new notifications on the server side ? That will slow down the server. Will it ?

Comment: @PHP NooB simple example included.

Comment: @Pravinda Amarathunga Well, sometimes you _do_ have to make your db queries or obtain your data by some other means...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Actually I am a total noob, and I need a little more help than that. I spent last night 2 hours, writing down scripts from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o91CVJZgLvA) and even though I finally made the script work and run as needed, I do not know where to place your code, here are the [Javascript](http://pastebin.com/BsHzuK7F) and the [PHP](http://pastebin.com/mKDGUNxE) scripts I wrote down. So, where exactly should I put your code?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I am still on that offer.

Comment: @PHP NooB don't take this in the wrong way, but as much as I can estimate your competency, this is probably not the task you want to start with to learn about JavaScrpt, PHP or simulating socket connections via long-poll. What you are asking is beyond StacOverflow's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (or study) some existing implementations, like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). There are a few others.

Essentially, you need to avoid having apache or the web server handle the request. Just like you would with a node.js server, you can start PHP from the command line and use the [server socket](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) functions to create a server and use socket_select to handle communications.

It could technically work throught the web server by keeping a loop active. However, the memory overhead of keeping a php process active per HTTP connection is typically too high. Creating your own server allows you to share the memory between connections.

Comment: In the classic polling method, there're no (or less) problems than comet ?

Comment: The classic polling method has a significant overhead as well by significantly increasing the hit count on your server. However, the memory is not kept allocated between polls.

Answer (score 1):

I used long polling for a chat application recently. After doing some research and playing it with a while here are some things I would recommend.

1) Don't long poll for more than about 20 seconds. Some browsers will timeout. I normally set my long poll to run about 20 seconds and send back an empty response at that point. Then you can use javascript to restart the long poll.

2) Every once in a while a browser will hang up. To help add a second level of error checking, I have a javascript timer run for 30 seconds and if no response has come in 30 seconds I abandon the ajax call and start it up again.

3) If you are using php make sure you use `session_write_close()`

4) If you are using ajax with Jquery you may need to use `abort()`

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918925/implementing-long-polling-with-jquery-and-php). More detail [here](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling) . And you should remember to use `$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });` when working with jquery.

Comment: You should explain it here, not just by mentioning links.